# Unity WebPlayer : WWW GET Requests fail in webplayer only, not in editor

Tags: unity, browser-based-games, cloud-computing

My question is about my game requesting data from my server-side cloud-based storage (I have the option of free public Dropbox or Amazon S3) via GET and the WWW class, and it not working only in the WebPlayer (works fine in the Editor).  By not working, I mean that the request is sent successfully, authorized and responded to by the cloud-service, but that WWW shows an error in the logs.  In the case of using Amazon S3, the Web Player even crashes, otherwise it just fails gracefully and the user is unable to move forward.

The Error log left by the webplayer says the following:

> WWW Error: Error when creating request. GET request with custom
>   headers is not supported. for URL:
>   https://my-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/myDir/myFile.json

Here's when I use a similar request to a public directory on Dropbox.  There is no crash, but the request also fails.

> WWW Error: Failed downloading
>   dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7782207/spare-change/weapons/0.json for
>   URL: dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7782207/spare-change/weapons/0.json

Try it for yourself: http://webroleplay.appspot.com   (currently using Dropbox, so not crashing the player)

username: test1

password: t

Comment: How is this specific to Unity exactly? It sounds like a more general programming question (which you should ask on SO). Can you provide more details about your approach?

Comment: Well, its not an issue with using these services; its the fact that it doesn't work in the WebPlayer after flawlessly working in the Editor.  Just wondered if anyone had encountered this issue with the Unity Web Player.  It must be something I am misunderstanding about the difference between the Editor and the Webplayer.  Unity Answers did not provide any help, so I wanted to check a broader audience of game developers.

Comment: Okay. So... what about the details of your approach? Otherwise, it doesn't look like there's anything to do here but guess, which makes it a question that isn't very on-topic here.

Comment: My approach to problem solving?  developing this feature?  What would you like to know?

Comment: What is the *code* you are running that results in failure? Are there any relevant settings you've applied? Et cetera. Not only does providing that information narrow the focus of your question, but it gives a change for people who know things about HTTP (but not Unity) to answer; as it stands you're currently addressing a more narrow audience here than at Unity Answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no code change to what I'm doing, and the settings are seemingly under the hood as Unity packages up a build for some given target and you deploy this file.  I suppose it could be a ...bug... in Unity Web Player.  More likely it is a limitation of some kind.  The behavior about which I am asking is the inherent difference between something executing in the Editor versus it running from the plugin in the browser.  I'm not arguing with you that more information would be helpful, but there is not much to provide from my point of view.